# How to use a pipe with lftp?

Tags: bash, pipe, lftp

I have files ending with apk in my desktop pc's terminal:

```
ls  | grep apk
DroidEdit_v1.23.6.apk
```

I connect to my android phone with lftp from my desktop pc:

```
lftp  192.168.31.130:3721
lftp 192.168.31.130:~> lcd Downloads
lcd ok, local cwd=/home/debian/Downloads
lftp 192.168.31.130:~> !ls
DroidEdit_v1.23.6.apk
```

Why can't the pipe be used in an lftp command?

```
lftp 192.168.31.130:/> !ls | !grep  apk
bash: line 1: !grep: command not found
```

Comment: Why `ls | grep`? Parsing the output of `ls` is generally a Very Bad Idea.  Why not just `ls *.apk`?

Comment: Just want to test if the pipe can work.

Answer (score 0):

Pipes **can** be used in a `!` (shell) lftp command:

```bash
$ lftp localhost
lftp localhost:~> !ls | grep rpm
rpmbuild
lftp localhost:~>
```

lftp passed your command to `$SHELL`, bash in your case as `bash -c 'ls | !grep apk'`; this means that bash was in [non-interactive mode](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#What-is-an-Interactive-Shell_003f), which means that [history expansion is disabled](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Interactive-Shell-Behavior.html). As a result, bash attempted to find a command literally named `!grep` and failed to do so.

Since lftp will pass all the text after `!` to the shell, you don't need to invoke lftp's `!` shell prefix for each command in the pipeline. Just use: `!ls | grep apk`, or as [DopeGhoti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/20246/dopeghoti) commented, simplify it to something like `!ls -d -- *apk*`.